# Image Forward and Backward in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am running sample application in react-native. I have 2 buttons i.e., forward and backward. How to write the functionality for below mentioned 2 points.

```
1. When i click forward button then screenshot is shown below.
```

[image]

```
2. When i click backward button then screenshot is shown below.
```

[image]

Comment: Try using zIndex with 1 and -1 and position absolute in View style
1 for forward and -1 for backward

Comment: Hi, @Kranthi Kumar thank you for your reply......... I don't know, how to write code......Please share the sample code for this.....

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in React.js, you could port it

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imageIndex: 2
    }

    this.setIndex = this.setIndex.bind(this)

  }

  setIndex(index) {

    this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, {
      imageIndex: index
    }));

  }

  render() {
  
    const { imageIndex } = this.state

    let imgClasses = [
      "ph bg-green",
      "ph bg-blue",
      "ph bg-green",
      "ph bg-red"
    ]

    return (
      <div className="container">  
        { imgClasses.map((img, i) =>
          <div onClick={ () => this.setIndex(i) }
          className={`${img}${ imageIndex == i ? " active" : ""}`}
          style = {{
              top: 60 * i,
              left: 60 * i
            }}>
          </div>
        ) } 
      </div>
    )

  }

}


ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.ph {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px #fff solid
}

.ph.active {
  z-index: 10;
}

.bg-green {
  background: #8BC34A;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: #03A9F4;
}

.bg-red { 
  background: #E91E63;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: hi @Adam azad, thank you for your reply..... But i don't know how to change your code into react-native code.......